# Lotus Notes Application, Web Based Converting

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Does anyone have tips or an ebook that can give me a good foundation on how to create applications in lotus notes using web browsers instead of clients. Links or tips are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Books are a good starter. But you'll find there is alot more to it than you see in books. So, here is a quick list of places to look.

**Books**

You've got these options for books (all downloadable as eBooks to)

[Classic Web development prior to Notes 8.5](http://www.packtpub.com/ibm-lotus-domino-classic-web-application-development-techniques/book) -- Reviews [here](http://alexkassabov.com/2011/04/29/ibm-lotus-domino-classic-web-application-development-techniques-book-review/) and [here](http://dominogavin.blogspot.com/2011/05/book-review-ibm-lotus-domino-classic_10.html)

[Latest Web stuff with Xpages if you have Notes 8.5+ (kindle/paper)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132486318)

There are [IBM wiki's (html)](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Redbooks%20Wiki:%20Best%20Practices%20for%20Domino%208.0%20Web%20Application%20Development). But have found the IBM wiki experience underwhelming. (The adjectives "half-ar$ed" and "piece-meal" comes to mind alot when reading these.)

[IBM's redbook site (pdf/html)](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/cgi-bin/searchsite.cgi?query=domino%20AND%20web%20AND%20development) has better produced content than the wiki's.

**Sites**

One of the best web development tip/technique sites for the trickier problems is [codestore.net](http://www.codestore.net/) and [nsftools.com](http://nsftools.com/)

[OpenNtf](http://openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf) a well used site for free code and solutions written by alot of smart people.

Quite a few good bloggers have "coagulated" on [planetLotus](http://planetlotus.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the links mate! Appreciate it. Kinda into reading the IBM's redbook site. I just started developing lotus notes for about 2 months now.

Comment: Great! Stackoverflow is a good site to get help as there are many experienced Devs watching the site. As Notes has been around for a while, most of the web-dev probs you'll encounter have a solution already published. The only advice is to avoid complicated scenarios at this early stage as you get to know how the server works, and how it behaves with browsers.

Comment: That's the sad part, some of my tasks are quite complicated for me specially that i just started but anyways, im quite liking it :),

Answer (score 1):

Try Searching for XPages in Google. Or start [here](http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Home.xsp)

Comment: Thanks Mate! Btw, would you happen to know how do i make my client based applications work on a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable http on the server, you should be able to see your domino applications from the web. You then need to modify them to make them a bit more web friendly. The basic technique for this is to have 2 design elements with the same alias, hide one from notes and the other from the web. This will make it a bit easier to make it functional from both the client and the web browser.

Other functionality which makes this a bit easier would be 'Pass through HTML', the [Domino CGI Variables](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/14b1b7f8f5286df385256c54004b9051?OpenDocument) and the 'WebQueryOpen' and 'WebQuerySave' events. As Jasper points out, XPages is the new sparkling way to do this, but it might not be an option for existing systems (It requires the latest version of Domino server). Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Jon! Yes, i'll the applications are made for lotus notes client and i need to make them still functional on the web, is saddens me that multivalue fields don't work when its on the browser :(

Comment: Multi-value fields do work in the browser. Your implementation may not work as you expected, but there is no design prohibition on multi-value fields.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Domino are you running? If it's an 8.5 variant, I would suggest you use XPages to bring your old client apps to the web (XPages are not an option in releases prior to 8.5).

As to how you go about this, that's well beyond the scope of an answer on Stack Overflow: it's a book in and of itself! To learn about web development with XPages, I suggest visiting some of the well-known sites out there, and perhaps picking up a course or two. Here are some links:

- http://xpages101.net
- http://www.qtzar.com/blogs/qtzar.nsf/htdocs/LearningXPages.htm
- http://notesin9.com/

(Also, IBM publish a book on XPages development, although I've not read it).

With regards "classic" Domino development, your best bet is to view your existing Notes app in a web browser and then start hacking on the default HTML generated (which is nasty). The best single resource out there for classic Domino web development tips and hacks is Jake Howlett's [Codestore](http://codestore.net)

Comment: I'm currently using 8.5, but some of the Notes applications were built in 7 and 6. There some applications that works to browsers already, the ones with templates. My dilemmas are the ground-up applications that were made. whew. thanks for  the links. Any idea how long is the learning curve of web based applications in domino?

Comment: Experienced Domino coders all have their own libraries of tips, tricks and code to roll out (e.g. how to re-do name-pickers, how to present views, etc.) There's no definitive path to doing this stuff, because every application is different. The learning curve for basic XPages implementation is not long though. In fact, if you have little experience of pre-XPage web dev with Domino, that will be in your favour.

Answer (score 0):

Start small, build yourself a small database with a subset of data and explore what you can do. I've been a notes client developer for 10+ years and doing domino web work for last three or four years and still on steep learning curve. Its a very powerful platform but you also need to know html as on many occasions the html that you see in the browser helped me pin down the faults in my application code.